# Physics with JOGL (Java, OpenGL)

Tags: java, physics, jogl

I'm doing a little project to teach myself about [JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/). Some of my ideas would be easier with a physics engine. Is there a 3D physics engine that's particularly good, or is commonly used with JOGL?

Answer (score 2):

You can find some recent examples of JOGL & JBullet used together [here](http://github.com/sgothel/jogl-demos/tree/master/src/jbullet/src/javabullet/demos/)

Answer (score 1):

Try jinngine.  http://code.google.com/p/jinngine/

I have looked into such frameworks but my apps have been simple enough to do physics more manually with JOGL, such as applying gravity to a reasonably small sized array of objects, making a distance map to calculate collisions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [bullet](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/) and [here the Java port](http://jbullet.advel.cz/).
Or at [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine#Real-time_physics_engines) where a few engines are listed.

Comment: Can bullet be easily used with Java?